# Unable to SSH to RHEL 6.5 after exporting to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have exported a VM from VMware ESX server to AWS by converting it in to OVF and using ec2-import-instance Command.
I am able to SSH this VM before exporting. sshd service is running fine and IPtables are updated to allow SSH. 
After launching the instance in AWS, I am getting the error "Connection Refused".
Security groups in AWS are configured to allow SSH from any computer.
I am not sure what I am missing here. can anyone help.

Below is the log from System log

�%G     Welcome to Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

Starting udev: %G[  OK  ]

Setting hostname HostName:  [  OK  ]

Setting up Logical Volume Management:   No volume groups found

[  OK  ]

Checking filesystems

Checking all file systems.

[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root

/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root: clean, 84140/393216 files, 566731/1572864 blocks

[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /boot] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/xvda1

/dev/xvda1: clean, 49/62592 files, 23356/250000 blocks

[  OK  ]

Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:  [  OK  ]

Mounting local filesystems:  mount: special device UUID=fb215306-b552-4bff-b07d-66706c336675 does not exist

mount: special device UUID=9a0267c2-78a2-4660-aa8a-ca306818d1f3 does not exist

mount: special device UUID=d869efbd-824e-406b-934e-0b47d9ef9a12 does not exist

mount: special device UUID=2cb8e09a-9cf5-4326-a713-af7e31dfd287 does not exist

mount: mount point /var/core does not exist

mount: special device UUID=c6be277c-4345-41be-b601-fe31d26eb3e5 does not exist

mount: mount point /var/log/audit does not exist

mount: mount point /var/opt/perf does not exist

[FAILED]

Enabling local filesystem quotas:  [  OK  ]

touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/random-seed': No such file or directory

chmod: cannot access `/var/lib/random-seed': No such file or directory

find: `/var/run': No such file or directory

/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit: line 610: /var/run/utmp: No such file or directory

chgrp: cannot access `/var/run/utmp': No such file or directory

chmod: cannot access `/var/run/utmp': No such file or directory

Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:  [  OK  ]

Entering non-interactive startup

Starting monitoring for VG rootvg:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "rootvg" monitored

[  OK  ]

Bringing up loopback interface:  ./network-functions: line 239: cd: /var/run/netreport: No such file or directory

[  OK  ]

Bringing up interface eth0:

Determining IP information for eth0...Can't create /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid: No such file or directory

done.

./network-functions: line 239: cd: /var/run/netreport: No such file or directory

[  OK  ]

Starting auditd: [FAILED]

Starting portreserve: [  OK  ]

Starting restorecond: [  OK  ]

Starting system logger: Can't open or create /var/run/syslogd.pid.

Can't write pid.

Comment: did you create key pair and assign it when create this ec2 instance?

Comment: yes, I have created the keypair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get start log. Go to AWS Console - EC2 - instances. Then Action - Instance Settings - Get System Log.
Find a line with Ssh service started. If it's OK the problem is in sshd and you should try to convert vm again. I'd add vnc or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your Response. Below is the log and I couldn't find anything related to ssh

Comment: The problem is in LVM: "Setting up Logical Volume Management: No volume groups found". So you haven't /var/run or /var and sshd can't start without it. You should create new vm ((

Comment: I am creating the instance using command ec2-import-instace -t m3.medium xxxx.vmdk -f VMDK  --architecture x86_64 --platform Linux -o accesskey -w secretkey -b bucketname .... I just imported a new instance and found the same log in the system log... I am not sure what I am missing here and VM is working fine before exporting to AWS

Comment: I think it's impossible because 
"VM Import/Export supports MBR-partitioned volumes that are formatted using ext2, ext3, ext4, Btrfs, JFS, or XFS filesystem. GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioned volumes are not supported."
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html

so your LVM partitions are not supported